# Python, Remove word start with specific character

Tags: python

How can I remove a word that starts with a specific char in python?

e.g..

```
string = 'Hello all please help #me'
```

I want to remove the word that starts with `#`

the result I want is:

```
Hello all please help
```

Comment: I don't understand why this question was downvoted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>>> a = "Hello all please help #me "
>>> filter(lambda x:x[0]!='#', a.split())
['Hello', 'all', 'please', 'help']
```

you can join it using whitespace:

```
>>> " ".join(filter(lambda x:x[0]!='#', a.split()))
'Hello all please help'
```

let me explain you step by step:

```
>>> a = "Hello all please help #me "
>>> a.split()                          # split, splits the string on delimiter, by default its whitespace
['Hello', 'all', 'please', 'help', '#me']
>>> >>> filter(lambda x:x[0]!='#', a.split())
['Hello', 'all', 'please', 'help']
```

`filter` return only those element for which condition is True.

Comment: Strings have a dedicated method for this thing: `str.startswith`.

Comment: _There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it_ `' '.join(word for word in txt.split(' ') if not word.startswith('#'))` is kind of self-explaining and obvious here IMHO.

Answer (score 8):

One problem with using `split` here is that it removes whitespace. For example,

```
In [114]: 'a  b \tc\nd'.split()
Out[114]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

So joining it back together again with `' '.join` *alters* the original string:

```
In [115]: ' '.join('a  b \tc\nd'.split())
Out[115]: 'a b c d'
```

If you want to preserve the original string and just remove words that begin with `#`, then you could use regex:

```
In [119]: import re

In [120]: re.sub(r'(\s)#\w+', r'\1', 'Hello all please help #me   but#notme')
Out[120]: 'Hello all please help    but#notme'
```

---

**Explanation**:

https://regex101.com has a handy tool to assist you in understanding regular expressions.
For example, [here is its explanation](https://regex101.com/r/kY6kM8/1) for what `"(\s)#\w+"` means:

```
1st Capturing group (\s)
    \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
# matches the character # literally
\w+ match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
```

Since this regex pattern begins by matching whitespace, `' #me'` matches, but `'but#notme'` does not.

The second argument to `re.sub`, `r'\1'`, is the replacement pattern. The `\1`
tells `re.sub` to replace the match with the first capturing group.  So the
match `' #me'` is replaced with a space `' '`.

Comment: please explain how above regular expression is working.

Answer (score 4):

Using the most obvious solution:

```
txt = 'Hello all please help #me'
# better to not use 'string' as variable name

' '.join(word for word in txt.split(' ') if not word.startswith('#'))
```

Note, that in this case it might be better to use `split(' ')` with explicit space as separator, in contrast to parameterless `split()` that is more common. This way you won't lose newlines or multiple spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this :

```
' '.join(word for word in "help #me please".split() if word[0]!='#')
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to [unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27196193/3734503), to catch the occurrence at the start of the sentence

```
> re.sub(r'(\s)#\w+', r'\1', '#Hello all please help #me   but#notme')
 '#Hello all please help    but#notme'

> re.sub(r'(\s)#\w+', r'\1', '#Hello all please help #me   but#notme')
 'all please help    but#notme'
```

> didn't have enough rep to comment